# Identify missing text sequence items using Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a geological dataset containing drillholes, depth intercepts and which geological unit was intersected.  Some of the geological unit intersections have not been added to the dataset and I'd like to use Python to generate a list of drillholes that have missing intersections.

I'd also like to know where in the sequence the intersection is missing.  Ideal output would be a file showing "DRILLHOLE, MISSING SEQUENCE ITEM".  Null values are acceptable in the UNIT column, as not every from-to interval is a named UNIT.

In the dataset below, the second hole is missing 'RED SS' in the unit sequence.  It may not be physically present - but for my use case it needs to be present in the database as a zero thickness. The input files are both csv files.

An example dataset might look like this (actual dataset is around 15,000 rows):

```
DRILLHOLE, TOP, BASE, MATERIAL, UNIT
HOLE-A, 0, 5, GRAVEL, 'BILL'S GRAVEL'
HOLE-A, 5, 7, CLAY, <NULL>
HOLE-A, 7, 10, SANDSTONE, 'RED SS'
HOLE-A, 10, 15, CLAYSTONE, <NULL>
HOLE-A, 15, 20, CLAYSTONE, 'BASEMENT'
HOLE-B, 0, 2, GRAVEL, 'BILL'S GRAVEL'
HOLE-B, 2, 4, CLAY, <NULL>
HOLE-B, 4, 11, SANDSTONE, <NULL>
HOLE-B, 11, 17, CLAYSTONE, <NULL>
HOLE-B, 17, 20, CLAYSTONE, 'BASEMENT'
```

The sequence list looks like (for example):

```
BILL'S GRAVEL
RED SS
BASEMENT
```

Comment: So you want to extract the names of holes that have "null" values in one or more cells? Or do you want to replace cells with "null" values with the value "0"?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html).  CSVs already do the work of identifying *which* fields are empty, so you've already got a huge leg up.

Answer (score 0):

You are having problems with the strings that make name the unit.
Try changing them ' for " into something lile this:

DRILLHOLE, TOP, BASE, MATERIAL, UNIT
HOLE-A, 0, 5, GRAVEL, "BILL'S GRAVEL"
HOLE-A, 5, 7, CLAY, "NULL"

Answer (score 0):

If you save your data in a text file called "data" with .txt extension, then running the following code in the directory in which your data file is located, you can find all rows with NULL values:

```
data = open("data.txt").read()
dataRows = data.split("\n")
for row in dataRows:
  cells = row.split(",")
  for cell in cells:
    if cell == " <NULL>":
      print row
```

Output from this code, using the sample data you provided:

```
HOLE-A, 5, 7, CLAY, <NULL>
HOLE-A, 10, 15, CLAYSTONE, <NULL>
HOLE-B, 2, 4, CLAY, <NULL>
HOLE-B, 4, 11, SANDSTONE, <NULL>
HOLE-B, 11, 17, CLAYSTONE, <NULL>
```

Comment: Thanks duhaime.  My question writing is obviously not the best.  I've altered it slightly to clarify my desired outcome.  In response to your handy answer - identifying null's will not help, as null is a valid value in the UNIT column.  If I had the ability, I'd select all non-null values, sort them by depth, then compare against the sequence file.  Anything missing or out of sequence -> dump to output file.

Comment: This helps a bit, but I'm still a little confused. Is the <NULL> value in row 4 supposed to be equal to Red SS or Basement? Are you merely trying to make sure that the values in the final column follow a particular order? Can you try to specify further what you're after so we can help?

Comment: Thanks.  The null value in row 4 can be null or one of the values in the sequence list (Red SS or Basement).  The key is that the UNIT values must appear in the correct order, as defined by the sequence list. This is only an example dataset - the sequence list runs to about 50 rows. For my desired clean dataset - each DRILLHOLE must have all items from the sequence list in it.  Currently they don't and I need to identify which hole and which sequence item are missing.

Comment: Rereading your comment - yes I am trying to make sure that the values in the final column follow a particular order, as defined by the sequence list. I want to know the missing sequence items in each drillhole.

Comment: Interesting. How do you know the final column of row 2 is Red SS instead of Bill's Gravel? Could the third row of Hole-B be Bill's Gravel, Red SS, or Basement? How do you know which to specify?

Comment: Always the last column - its interpreted by the geologist.  A MATERIAL doesn't have to have a UNIT, but a UNIT must have a MATERIAL. For Hole-B, row 2,3 or 4, UNIT could be Red SS or NULL.  The output should contain a row stating ['Hole-B', 'Red SS'] - indicating that Hole-B has 'Bills Gravel' and 'Basement', but 'Red SS' is not present between these two other units.